# Can אֲדֹנָי refer to a person or just to God?

Tags: hebrew, ezra-nechemya

In Book of Ezra chapter 10 No.3 the Bible uses the Hebrew word אֲדֹנָי to talk about Ezra.

I thought this word was used only when talking about God.

What does this word mean?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Nasser! Thank you for sharing your question. To learn more about the site, consider taking the following two minute [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: "But this word used when talking about the God only" - this isn't true. See, for example, [Shmuel I Chapter 25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15854)

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir ( by the way i am sorry about my English..it is not god )

Comment: Hi Nasser. In the first you cited, *Adonai* IS a reference to G-d. Rash"i commentary, for one, confirms this. Where have you seen this translated otherwise for this verse?

Comment: If we go back to strong on this website we will find this

Comment: http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=0136 .... talk about this word in the beginning say it has two definهtion one to talk about god and second to talk about man .. after that they say it is use with god only? what is truth

Comment: hello sir .. which number in Shmuel I chapter 25 used this word to talk bout man ?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I've made an edit to clarify the question, though I didn't know what to do with your Strong's link.  (That seems to contain the answer -- there are two meanings.)  If I've misunderstood please do [edit] further.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser, it starts at verse 24 and continues from there.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/58945. Also, this title can sometimes be used (not as a divine name) to mean something like "sir(s)" (e.g. [*B'reishis* 19:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0119.htm#2); see [*Sh'vu'os* 35b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=35b&format=text)).

Comment: @Nasser "by the way i am sorry about my English..it is not god" neither was Ezra :)

Comment: I told that my English not good :) ...yes i have misunderstood in this word, in Strong's link said this is two defintion on of god and one of men and after that say "am emphatic form of 113; the Lord (used as a proper name of
God only):-(my) Lord.
see HEBREW for 0113 "

Comment: anyone can explain this to me why there is difference between two definitions .. first ( two usage ) second one ( only one usage for god )

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you cite [this link](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=0136). I believe you were confused due to English not being your first language by this sentence: "used as a proper name of God only." In context, that sentence does not mean that the word אֲדֹנָי can only refer to God. It means that the word אֲדֹנָי refers to God **when it is used as a proper name**.

Indeed, as Yishai pointed out in the comments, that word certainly can be used to refer to people (although the verse in Ezra that you cited does seem to be using אֲדֹנָי to refer to God, not Ezra as you suggest. Rashi confirms this).

In [Genesis 18:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#3), the word אֲדֹנָי refers (according to at least one position in the Talmud [[Shevuot 35b](http://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Shevuoth.pdf)]) to the angels who were approaching Avraham rather than to God.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27318/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-can--refer-to-a-person-or-just-to-god).